# Android Maps with Custom Marker (text on the marker)

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have never worked on maps api before. I want to implement maps like the below picture. I am getting the data from a web service using which i can get the event count to be displayed on markers.
The basic functionality is that once user zoom in then the map markers will expand and so the marker counts.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to customize the markers like this.
2. How can I handle the marker count on zoom in, zoom out event.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the library which I mentioned in answer

Comment: @skadoosh I have gone through the documentation of the mentioned library and it seems helpful. I will confirm once the implementation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to count markers and display the way it is in picture. 
Google has a library called [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/)

The one you need is called

> Marker clustering — handles the display of a large number of points. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZnVraO1mT4)

Comment: as its working you can now click on that checkbox on my answer **:) :)**

Answer (score 0):

The Android-Maps-Utils has Marker Clustering Utility. Below are the steps:

1. Add `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'` in your build.gradle.
2. Add below permissions in your Manifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="your.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   ```
3. Create a class which gives you position of the marker as LatLng Object.

   public class MarkerItem implements ClusterItem {

   ```
   private final LatLng mPosition;

   public MarkerItem (double lat, double lon) {
       mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lon);
   }

   @Override
   public LatLng getPosition() {
       return mPosition;
   }
   ```
4. Add ClusterManager inside your Activity/Fragment

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

   ```
   private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

   // Declare a variable for the cluster manager.
   ClusterManager<MarkerItem> mClusterManager;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
               (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

       supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

       mGoogleMap = googleMap;

       setUpClusterer();
   }

   private void setUpClusterer() {

       // Position the map.
       mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

       // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
       // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
       mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this, mGoogleMap);

       // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
       // manager.
       mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
       mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

       // Add cluster items (markers) to the cluster manager.
       addItems();
   }

   /**
    * Generate dummy coordinates
    */
   private void addItems() {

       // Set some lat/lng coordinates to start with.
       double lat = 51.5145160;
       double lng = -0.1270060;

       // Add ten cluster items in close proximity, for purposes of this example.
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           double offset = i / 60d;
           lat = lat + offset;
           lng = lng + offset;
           MarkerItem offsetItem = new MarkerItem(lat, lng);
           mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
       }
   }
   ```

This library automatically handles the clustering part.

I hope this will help!

For more details: Please follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering)